# SQL query to update an empty field to match one from another table

Tags: sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update a date field in an HFSQL database. In the `Patient` table there is a `Patient.PatInserted` field where some of the records are blank. The patient IDs are `Patient.PatID`. I am trying to fill the `Patient.PatInserted` fields to match the oldest record from another table. The table is called `Test` and the records from here are tied to the `Patient` table using `Test.TesPatIDFK`. I want to insert the oldest `Test.TesInserted` record for each patient into their `Patient.PatInserted` one.

I'm new to SQL and I can't get the select query to show more than just the oldest `Patient.PatInserted` record. I'm trying to get the oldest record for each individual `TesPatIDFK`. I'm trying to just do the SELECT portion for now.

This is my latest code for the SELECT query:

```sql
SELECT
  DISTINCT Patient.PatID,
  Patient.PatInserted,
  Patient.PatSalutation,
  Test.TesPatIDFK,
  Test.TesInserted 
FROM 
  Patient JOIN Test ON Patient.PatID = Test.TesPatIDFK
WHERE
  Patient.PatID = Test.TesPatIDFK
AND
  Test.TesInserted = (SELECT MIN(Test.TesInserted) FROM Test)
AND
  Patient.PatInserted LIKE ''
```

Here is a basic view of the table structure. I believe `PatInserted` and `TesInserted` are timestamps, just with slightly different formats:

```
      Patient
___________________
PatID | PatInserted
___________________
1,626 | 
___________________
   2  | 16/02/2021
```

```
                  Test
_______________________________________
TesID | TesPatIDFK |    TesInserted
_______________________________________
 1303 |    1,626   |25/10/1201 15:04:34
_______________________________________
  8   |     2      |16/02/2021 14:05:51
```

This is the result from my query:

```
PatID | PatInserted | TesPatIDFK |    TesInserted
______________________________________________________
1,626 |             |    1,626   | 25/10/1201 00:00:00
```

Comment: Is your end goal to do an update or a select?

Comment: Is your `PatInserted` column a string, or a timestamp?  You are checking for an empty string.  If it's a timestamp, you probably want `patinserted is null`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The end goal is an UPDATE but I’m just trying to get the SELECT portion that I’m going to use in the UPDATE

Comment: Why is the `DISTINCT` there, why are you getting duplicates? Sample data (for each table) would help, we need to recreate your actual query.

Comment: @Charlieface I thought `DISTINCT` would return just one line for each `PatID`. I'll update the post to show an example of each table. Sorry about that, I haven't used stackoverflow in ages

Comment: Your query is doing exactly what you asked it to, what's wrong with the result?

Comment: Why have the PatInserted column at all, when you can always just select the timestamp from the test table? Or do you intend to drop the test table after the update?

Comment: @Andrew I'm only getting that line. There are thousands of records in the `Patient` and `Test` tables, and in some cases there are multiple `Test` records tied to each `Patient`. I need the oldest `TesInserted` for every `Patient` in the result

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I'm keeping all of the tables, I just put it in. No particular reason. I'll drop it when I do the `UPDATE`

Comment: `SELECT MIN(Test.TesInserted) FROM Test` returns a single value. So, with `AND Test.TesInserted = (SELECT MIN(Test.TesInserted) FROM Test)` your query will select this one row only, of course.

Answer (score 0):

1. You want to update the column PatInserted in the table Patient, so `update patient set patinserted = ... where ...`.
2. You want to update empty PatInserted. This should be a timestamp, so I'd expect `where patinserted is null`. You, however, use `PatInserted LIKE ''`, which assumes that PatInserted is a string and that string is not null, but the empty string. And `LIKE` doesn't seem to make much sense, anway. `LIKE` does pattern matching. If you are looking for equality, use `=`. If the column is a string, you should change it to `TIMESTAMP` and use `where patinserted is null`.
3. In order to find the minimum TesInserted for a PatID, use a correlated subquery (correlated = related to the updating row by refering to its ID).

The complete statement:

```
update patient 
set patinserted = 
(
  select min(test.tesinserted) 
  from test
  where test.tespatidfk = patient.patid
)
where patinserted is null;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that says "No analysis opened <Test> file not described."

Comment: I had a typo (text instead of test in one instance). This doesn't match the error message, but may be the issue. Please try again with the amended query. This is very basic standard SQL, so it should work in HFSQL just like in every other DBMS.

Comment: I saw that one. I'm still getting the same error though

Comment: Sorry to hear that. As mentioned, this is very basic standard SQL. It doesn't throw an error in other DBMS, as can be seen here: https://dbfiddle.uk/VRDf_Csh So it must be something about HFSQL. Why is this refering to a "file" named Test, when it's a table? Does the table test exist? Can you `select * from test`? Must you make this table available somehow? I don't know this DBMS, so I cannot help further. Try to find out what's happening by writing very simple statements until you hit the error.

Comment: Yeah it is an active table. I'll keep at it and see where I get, and hopefully I'll pick up enough so I don't have to ask here. Thank you very much for your help :)